# RoR ActionMailer sending inline attachments instead of regular ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I try to send NOT INLINE attachment by mail:

```
m = ActionMailer::Base.mail(:to => "ex@ex.pl", :from => "ex1@ex.pl", :subject=>"test")
m.attachments["test.csv"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/test.csv")
m.deliver
```

When recipient is getting mail, attachment is showing INLINE (mail's body contains text of attachment).

Rails 3.2.19
Ruby 2.1.2p95

Give me advice, please, how to fix it and send attachment like file attached to mail ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work for me:

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def send_report
        attachments["test.csv"] = {mime_type: 'text/csv', content: File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'tasks', 'test.csv'))}
        mail(:to => "", :from => "", :subject=>"") do |format|
                format.text {render :text => ""}
        end
    end
end

ReportMailer.send_report.deliver
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify mime type and content disposition:

```
m.attachments["test.csv"] = {mime_type: 'text/csv',                            
                             content: File.read("#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/test.csv"),
                             content_disposition: 'attachment'}
```